# Can't boot after recent system update

Tags: grub2, 9.10

After recent system update (I think I saw something kernelish but don't really remember) my Ubuntu becomes unbootable. When I select "Ubuntu" from the boot menu, I'm greeted by a GRUB console and I don't know what to do (typing help shows some helpful commands for gods, unfortunately I'm a mere mortal).

I'm doing this on Windows XP now. How do I go back to the future?

Edit:
The Ubuntu was installed using WUBI

Comment: A very nice description of the problem indeed, I like your style :) But I have 2 questions: are you sure it is a Grub console (looking something like `grub >`)? If so, can you post the output of boot_info_script from a LiveCD? http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Was it booting from the live CD and installing to a real partition or using WUBI and installing from Windows ?

Comment: WUBI, installing on NTFS

Comment: @arrange: the prompt is sh:grub>, boot_info_script: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need to boot into a live CD and Recover GRUB visit this [Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) link - the steps are not that hard to follow you just need to be sure of the Ubuntu install partition and use the 9.10 install Cd you have.

Comment: Unfortunately I use WUBI

Comment: Simply choose Windows at boot and then you can reinstall from within Windows then.

Comment: okay I'll need to rescue my home first. Thanks.

Comment: If your happy using Ubuntu I suggest you format the partition and dual boot - WUBI is really really meant for those that just want to run Ubuntu inside a Windows environment and does sometimes have issues with updates that can break the installation, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide for more info.